# A proper way to install PEM certifiate in Android

Tags: android, keychain, pem, pkcs#12

I am developing an Android project.

I have a PEM certificate string:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEczCCA1ugAwIBAgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQQFAD..AkGA1UEBhMCR0Ix
EzARBgNVBAgTClNvbWUtU3RhdGUxFDASBgNVBAoTC0..0EgTHRkMTcwNQYD
VQQLEy5DbGFzcyAxIFB1YmxpYyBQcmltYXJ5IENlcn..XRpb24gQXV0aG9y
...MANY LINES...
It8una2gY4l2O//on88r5IWJlm1L0oA8e4fR2yrBHX..adsGeFKkyNrwGi/
7vQMfXdGsRrXNGRGnX+vWDZ3/zWI0joDtCkNnqEpVn..HoX
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

(assigned above certificate string to a variable named `CERT_STR`)

I decode above PEM string to byte array:

```
byte[] pemBytes = Base64.decode(
                CERT_STR.replaceAll("-----(BEGIN|END) CERTIFICATE-----", "")
                        .replaceAll("\n", "")
                        .getBytes("UTF-8"),
                Base64.DEFAULT
        );
```

I try to programmatically install the PEM certificate to my Android phone by following code:

```
Intent intent = KeyChain.createInstallIntent();
// because my PEM only contains a certificate, no private key, so I use EXTRA_CERTIFICATE
intent.putExtra(KeyChain.EXTRA_CERTIFICATE, pemBytes);// above PEM bytes
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

When run my code (in Android 7 device), the Android system certificate installer app pops up the window, when I press "OK" button of that window, I got following log:

```
 java.io.IOException: stream does not represent a PKCS12 key store
  at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStoreSpi.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStoreSpi.java:793)
  at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1247)
  at com.android.certinstaller.CredentialHelper.loadPkcs12Internal(CredentialHelper.java:396)
  at com.android.certinstaller.CredentialHelper.extractPkcs12Internal(CredentialHelper.java:364)
  at com.android.certinstaller.CredentialHelper.extractPkcs12(CredentialHelper.java:354)
  at com.android.certinstaller.CertInstaller$1.doInBackground(CertInstaller.java:328)
  at com.android.certinstaller.CertInstaller$1.doInBackground(CertInstaller.java:327)
```

**My questions:**

1. I have used [EXTRA_CERTIFICATE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html#EXTRA_CERTIFICATE) & set it to `intent`, I am NOT using [EXTRA_PKCS12](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html#EXTRA_PKCS12), but from the log, Android system thinks I am installing PKCS#12 keystore. Why?
2. What is the correct way to programmatically install PEM certificate in Android?

Comment: `stream does not represent a PKCS12 key store` any reason to not try converting it to PKCS12 then?

Comment: But I still want to know what is the proper way to install PEM in Android, that's the point of my question.

Comment: This appears to be exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40464815/install-x509-certificate-programmatically-in-my-case

Comment: What wersion of android platfrom do you use? I'm tryed to run your code and in worked good. I seen Toast "<inputted_sert_name> is installed". Android 5.1.0

Comment: I am running it in Android 7

Comment: @Leem.fin Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, as said @Sergey Nikitin. This starred [example](https://github.com/nelenkov/keystore-test/blob/master/src/org/nick/keystoretest/KeystoreTest.java) at Github is using similar code

I have reviewed the Android 7.1 source code of [CredentialHelper](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/CertInstaller/+/android-7.1.0_r5/src/com/android/certinstaller/CredentialHelper.java) and [CertInstaller](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/CertInstaller/+/android-7.1.0_r5/src/com/android/certinstaller/CertInstaller.java) to trace your exception log. The unique reachable path to execute the `pkcs12` loader at

```
 com.android.certinstaller.CredentialHelper.extractPkcs12(CredentialHelper.java:354)
```

is the method `onScreenlockOk`

```
private void onScreenlockOk() {
    if (mCredentials.hasPkcs12KeyStore()) {
        if (mCredentials.hasPassword()) {
            showDialog(PKCS12_PASSWORD_DIALOG);
        } else {
            new Pkcs12ExtractAction("").run(this);
        }
```

which is protected by `CredentialHelper.hasPkcs12KeyStore()`

```
boolean hasPkcs12KeyStore() {
    return mBundle.containsKey(KeyChain.EXTRA_PKCS12);
}
```

I have not found default assigned values or alternative paths, so I deduce that `KeyChain.EXTRA_PKCS12` is being used in some way. It is a weird behaviour, may be you have a clean&rebuild issue?

I suggest to debug the code including Android CertInstaller class to ensure the values of the Extras and ensure that the executed code is the expected